# Using string.at() or string[]

Tags: c++, string

In C++, is it bad to use `string[x]` to get a char at a specific location?
Most people use `string.at(x)` but is there a reason why `string[x]` is bad?

Comment: Most people use `string.at()`?

Comment: The real question is not "whether one is better or worse", but "what's the difference and when to use each".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I'm aware most people **don't** use `string.at()`. If your code is well written and well understood, you should always be working within the bounds of your string so don't need the run-time bounds checking that `string.at()` provides. Same goes for the other sequence containers with `.at()`.

Comment: In addition, random access in strings is seldom required, the vast majority of string operations can be performed using sequential access (ie. using iterators instead of indexes). Same goes with other sequence containers.

Comment: +1 for designing code to work correctly rather than adding random hacks to catch mistakes.